# What does it take to compare ConfigValue from application.conf with a String parameter in my controller?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I am struggling with using the values returned by Play.current.configuration for simple String comparison in my controller.  The value I .get from the application.conf file node doesn't seem to ever make it through my string comparison.  It is as if it is not a String.  Here is the application.conf parameter.

```
admin.users=[
  { "userName" : "admin", "password" : "secret" },
  { "userName" : "rkuhar", "password" : "alsosecret" }
]
```

Here is the controller method

```
def isAuthenticated(userName: String, credentials: String): Boolean = {
  Play.current.configuration.getObjectList("admin.users") match {
    case Some(adminUsers) => {
      log.debug("admin.users: %s".format(adminUsers))
      for (adminUser <- adminUsers) {
        val adminUserName: String = adminUser.get("userName").render()
        log.trace("userName: %s, adminUserName: %s".format(userName,adminUserName))
        if (adminUserName == userName) {
          log.trace("USER MATCH")
        } else {
          log.trace("skip user")
        }
      }
      "admin123".equals(credentials)
    }
    case None => {
      log.warn("application.conf produced no admin.users")
      false
    }
  }
}
```

Why does my simple String comparison fail to ever find a match?  It is as if ConfigValue.render() doesn't actually return a String?  My logging shows this when isAuthenticated is provided with a userName of "admin".

```
2013-06-06T13:07:54.480 [trace] c.a.Sessions$ DSN: APV: RID: - userName: admin, adminUserName: "admin"
```

Note how the userName value passed in comes out of logging as just admin but the adminUserName has quotes around it "admin".

How to I get the Play framework to give me the actual String value of the JSON fields rather than the String Value of a String Value of the JSON fields?

This Play 2.1 learning curve feels increasingly steep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is the render() call. The unwrapped() method is a better choice for what I'm trying to get done; extract the value from a specific field in the JSON.  There is certainly a better way to do this whole thing but I'm new to this and this is the best I've figured out:

```
  def isAuthenticated(userName: String, credentials: String): Boolean = {
    Play.current.configuration.getObjectList("admin.users") match {
      case Some(adminUsers) => {
        for (adminUser <- adminUsers) {
          val adminUserName = adminUser.get("userName").unwrapped()
          if (userName == adminUserName) {
              val adminUserCredentials = adminUser.get("credentials").unwrapped()
              log.trace("adminUserCredentials: " + adminUserCredentials)
              if ( credentials == adminUserCredentials) {
                return true
              }
          }
        }
        false
      }
      case None => {
        log.warn("application.conf produced no admin.users")
        false
      }
    }
  }
```

It appears that this aspect of Play 2.1 is still implemented in Java do there are no ScalaDocs for it.  The documentation for the Typesafe stuff referenced from the is here:  http://typesafehub.github.io/config/latest/api/

Comment: wouldn't it solve your problem to use adminUser.getString instead of adminUser.get ?